# Enterprise manager 12c jmx operations

Tags: oracle, jmx, oracle-enterprise-manager

Wanted to know if OEM Cloud Control 12c supports Custom JMX operations as in JConsole. I've instrumented my java application to add some JMX Operations which take in a String as parameter, does some processing and return the result.

Example: Something like [the add() operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html)

I tried using the jmxcli utility for creating a metadata plugin, but looks like the arguments (or parameters) to the JMX Operation should be hardcoded while creating the plugin. Is there any other way to run JMX operations on user-defined parameters in OEM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a custom UI, the scope of this QueryDescriptor should be "USER". The custom UI will be used to input this value, and this value will be used in the JMX fetchlet.